# (Godot) They are also nodes of objects

Tags: object, oop, godot

I want to understand if for example a game object like a SPRITE that if inserted alone represents a scene in godot is related to the concept of OOP object, in practice I want to understand if it is also an OOP object....

Answer (score 1):

In Godot, a node is an object. Not all objects are nodes.

---

We can see the documentation for [`Node`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html), that it inherits from `Object`, where `Object` is the base class for everything in Godot.

And, of course, [`Sprite`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_sprite.html) is a `Node`.

So, all `Sprite`s are `Node`s, and all `Node`s are `Object`s.

---

**What is a scene?**

First of all, **scenes are not C++ classes.** *I hope this is evident.*

Second, there is something called scene inheritance, which suggest scenes are some kind of classes. However, we cannot extend them in code. **Scenes are not classes.**

Third, we can create `Node`s from scene files. If the scene file is not a class, that suggest they are [prototypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming). But if scenes are prototypes, how do we explain scene inheritance? Well, as it turns out, **scenes are not prototypes.** It is much simpler than that…

**Scenes are `Node`s.**

---

As you know, when you tell Godot to add a scene file to the Scene panel you get an item that has a special icon. And - by default - you don't see any children that where in that scene file. This is only they way they are shown in the UI.

Perhaps you wonder how does it look like in memory. Is there a special type of `Node` for any scene files you add? And the answer is NO. They are regular `Node`s.

When you tell Godot to add a scene file to the Scene panel, Godot loads it and instantiate it, getting a `Node`. Then Godot adds that `Node` as a child where you told it.

---

So how does it remember that that `Node` was added from a scene file?

The `Node`s have a `filename` property that tell us from where it was loaded. So when you are serializing a `Node` to an scene file, and it has some child `Node` that has a `filename` set, instead of serializing that child `Node` to the same scene file... It is serialized to the file indicated by its `filename`, and then included by reference.

Of course, the `filename` property is not visible in the Inspector panel.

---

But then, what is scene inheritance?

When you have a serialized <strike>scene</strike> `Node` (i.e. a scene file), it contains the properties, scripts, children, connections and so on. And as said above, it can include other files by reference.

Scene inheritance is the special case of inclusion where the serialized `Node` is defined as another scene. That is scene inheritance is extension by inclusion.

---

Finally there is something called `SceneTree`. The game will have an `SceneTree` object (unless you instantiate more), and it references a `Node` which is considered the current scene.

Comment: Great explaination !

Comment: I thank you for your explanation but just wanted to know:
If I insert in the empty scene, a sprite for example, is this sprite an object programming object if I link it to a script or if I refer to it from another script linked to another game object(for example another sprite)? I read what you wrote above but I didn't see in particular that you explained about this point

Comment: "All Sprites are Nodes, and all Nodes are Objects." Says the answer. I do not understand your confusion. An sprite is an object regardless if you add it as child of another node, regardless if you attach a script to it, and regardless if you use it from another script. @Gius