# A gdscript(godot engine) file is used to initialize a node

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am having a little trouble interpreting the utility of a godot engine gdscript file. I have searched the web and found that a gdscript file is a class and this class inherits from the node I attached it to. My question, however, is a gdscript class file a file that is used to "initialize" an object/node in some sense as is the case, for example, in a pure object-oriented language such as Java that when I define an object in the "main," I initialize it via the constructor?

Comment: Yes, a gdscript can initialize an object. This can be done through the inherited `_init()` and/or `_ready()` functions, depending on the use case. `_init()` is the constructor, while `_ready()` is used when initialization depends on other objects in the scene tree. See https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#class-constructor

Answer (score 2):

*To keep things stright, when I say GDScript I'm talking about the language, and when I say `GDScript` I'm talking about the Godot class that is called that way.*

---

> a gdscript file is a class

Correct.

Well, a file is a file, is a file, is a file. But GDScript scripts are classes, and they are loaded from, and saved to, gd files. So, saying that the gd file is a class is a good shorthand.

---

> this class inherits from the node I attached it to

You specify in the script what class it extends. Which might or might not be subclass of `Node`. If you are going to attach the script to a `Node`, it must extend the class of the `Node`.

---

> is a gdscript class file a file that is used to "initialize" an object/node in some sense as is the case, for example, in a pure object-oriented language such as Java that when I define an object in the "main," I initialize it via the constructor?

A class that you can use in GDScript could be a build-in class (which are defined in Godot source code, which is C++, by the way), or a class defined in some script language, including GDScript.

A class defined in GDScript in runtime will be an instance of the `GDScript` class, which are `Resource`s that are loaded from, and saved to, gd files.

The `GDScript` class is what other languages would call a [metaclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaclass). That is, the instances of the `GDScript` class (the `GDScript` objects) are classes.

---

In general, the instance of the a class is an object (in Godot, Java, or whatever).

Godot classes extend the `Object` class, so their instances are `Object`s.

If the class extends `Node` (which extends `Object`), then the instances of the class are `Node`s. But the script does not have to extend `Node`. For example, it is useful to create custom classes that extend `Resource` (i.e. it is useful to define custom `Resource` types).

---

Yes, classes have constructors. In Godot classes expose an static method called `new` which you use to create instances, calling it results in a call to the constructor. And you override a virtual method `_init` to give custom behavior to the constructor. *If you want to split hairs, the `_init` method is technically an initializer, not a constructor, but we will call it constructor anyway*. In GDScript you cannot define additional constructors.

*You might also be interested in the `_ready` method, which is often used for initialization, but that mechanism is related to the scene tree, not to classes.*

---

Perhaps you get a better grasp of this if we think of it from the point of view of what you do and what happens.

You create a new gd file in your project. Godot will try to load this gd file as a `GDScript` instance. To do this the resource loader for `GDScript` will create a new `GDScript` instance and give the code (which it gets from opening the gd file, reading it), and then have the `GDScript` instance parse it. Which might fail leading to some error output, or not.

When you execute the game, it will do the same thing (except the resource paths of the gd file might resolve to reading a packaged resource in an exported build).

Now, once you have a `GDScript` instance, you can call `new` on it. Which will create a new `Object` according to script, setting its methods and properties, initializing them, and executing `_init`.

Alright, but you might not be dealing with a `GDScript` instance, but using a named class. So when parsing and also when executing the code, Godot needs to be able to resolve the name of the class to either a script class or a build-in class… So Godot keeps dictionaries that map class names to the classes. *You can give a name to the classes defined in GDScript with the `class_name` keyword.*

---

Now, I said that when you call `new` on the `GDScript` instance it will create a new `Object` according to the script. That means it will look for the class the script says it extends and create an instance of that.

In particular, if we are talking about a class that extends `Node` (or some subclass of it), Godot will create a instance `Node` (or the appropriate subclass), attach the `GDScript` instance itself to this new `Node` instance, then allocate the variables the script defines and set them to their default values, *emit the `"script_changed"` signal*, and call `_init`.

---

We haven't talked about scenes, by the way. I'm going to link you a few of my prior answers if you want to know more about that:

- [Nodes and Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70465254/402022)
- [Scene instancing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/194937/10408)
- [The ready mechanism](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/192257/10408)