# What is the main scene in a Godot game?

Tags: godot, godot4

In the Godot engine, it is possible to define one scene as the "main scene". In the tutorials provided in the docs, the "main scene" is simply the scene your game starts with, and that is also the description I can find in various places.

Yet, it is not yet clear to me which one of the following is true about the "main scene", or whether actually both are possible and it is just an implementation decision:

- The main scene is the first scene displyed when the game starts. In more complex games, it will be replaced once or multiple times throughout the run of the game.
- The main scene is the root scene filling the screen throughout the game's lifetime. Thus, it contains just e.g. a title bar and a large subview or something. Whenever the "screen" (whatever the user sees, e.g. a full-screen main menu vs. the actual in-game screen) switches, the content of the subview changes.

Is it the former, the latter, or both, depending on what I decide during implementation?

Comment: Close voter, how is this *not* about programming or software development? I am asking about a concept of a given framework in a particular programming environment.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but now that you mention it, it is not a programming problem you are trying to solve.  It could be a better fit for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Theraot: I fail to see how using a specific feature of a programming library is not a programming problem, but I agree [gamedev.se] would have been an even better fit in terms of finding the right people to answer the question, so I'll make sure to post any other questions somewhat related to Godot in the future over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

The main scene is the first scene to be instantiated as current scene.

---

**What is an scene (short version)?**

Godot does not have an `Scene` class. So the concept of scenes on runtime is somewhat vague.

There are scene files, which have `PackedScene` objects serialized. You can load them into `PackedScene` objects, from which you can instantiate `Node`s. So the scene files have trees of `Node`s serialized for reuse. *They could be props in your game, complete stages, UI elements, etc.*

I go into more detail in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70465254/402022).

---

**What is the current scene?**

During normal operation, Godot will have a `SceneTree` which will have a `root`, and the `root` will be a `Viewport` (a `Window` in Godot 4, which is a kind of `Viewport`). As children of the `root` you are going to find the autoloads, the current scene, and whetever else you have added there from your code.

So, the `SceneTree` has a concept of a current scene - which, again, is a `Node` - and there is an API to change the current scene (which is completely optional).

Refer to the article on [autoloads](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/singletons_autoload.html) for details.

Exceptions to "normal operation" are shenanigans with the `SceneTree` (there is a mechanism to replace it, or you could instantiate more than one from your code).

---

**What are scenes for?**

The intended use of the current scenes is to be stages or scenarios in your game. So when the player moves in the game world to a new area, or when it completes the current stage, you would switch to the next one.

You will want somethings to survive the change of current scene, for that you can use autoload (among other mechanisms). And, of course there would be elements that you want to reuse in multiple scenes... Well, those are scenes too!

You are not limited to instantiate scenes as current scene. Notably you can add an instance of a scene as a child of something else. Either during design (e.g. placing props in an scenario) or during game play (e.g. spawning projectiles).

*So scenes fullfill the role of "prefabs", I like to put it this way: Godot does not have a scene/prefab distinction.*

This also means that you do not need to change the current scene at all. Instead you can have your UI in the current scene, and instantiate other scenes inside of it.

---

**What is the main scene?**

Again, during normal operation, when the game launches Godot will load as first current scene, whatever you have configured as main scene (the configuration is in project settings). So, in this context main scene refers to the scene file.

The article [Nodes and Scenes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/nodes_and_scenes.html) coverts how to set up the main scene.

Exceptions to "normal operation" include launching a secondary scene for debugging, and launching Godot to run a script from command line (which also is a way to replace the `SceneTree`).

---

**Your questions**

> The main scene is the first scene displyed when the game starts. In more complex games, it will be replaced once or multiple times throughout the run of the game.

The first current scene will be an instance of the main scene. And yes, you can change the current scene afterwards. *Personally, I consider the current scene API a beginners approach. More complex games will take control of the process to allow them to move objects from one scene to the other, add scene transitions, loading screens, etc.*

You are going to see an splash screen first, and autoloads will load before the main scene. *So it is not the first thing displayed.*

> The main scene is the root scene filling the screen throughout the game's lifetime. Thus, it contains just e.g. a title bar and a large subview or something. Whenever the "screen" (whatever the user sees, e.g. a full-screen main menu vs. the actual in-game screen) switches, the content of the subview changes.

The main scene might fill the root `Viewport`, and it might exist for the lifetime of the game. This depends on how you use it (I use it that way, but you don't have to).

In Godot 3 the title bar is not part of the the root `Viewport`, instead you have limited access to it via `OS`. In Godot 4 you have limited access to the title bar from the root `Window` directly, and the window related functions that used to be on `OS` are now in `DisplayServer`.